# JMock unexpected invocation

Tags: java, junit, jmock, assertion

Below I am just trying to mock a class named TestWrapper and set 'allowing' expecations on it. However, when setting expectations I get error. When using easymock and just setting expectations, this doesn't seem to happen

```
import org.jmock.Expectations;
import org.jmock.Mockery;
import org.jmock.integration.junit4.JUnit4Mockery;
import org.jmock.lib.legacy.ClassImposteriser;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class CustomerPaymentProgramConverterTest {

    TestWrapper paymentType;

    Mockery mockery = new JUnit4Mockery() {{
            setImposteriser(ClassImposteriser.INSTANCE);
    }};

    @Before
    public void setupMethod() {

      paymentType = mockery.mock(TestWrapper.class);

    }

    @Test
    public void testFromWebService() {

        mockery.checking(new Expectations() {{

                    //debugger throws error on the line below.
                    allowing(paymentType.getScheduledPaymentAmount());
                    will(returnValue(new BigDecimal(123)));
                    allowing(paymentType.getScheduledPaymentConfirmationNumber());
                    will(returnValue(121212L));
        }});

    }
}
```

TestWrapper.class

```
 //Class I am mocking using JMock
 public class TestWrapper {

     public  java.math.BigDecimal getScheduledPaymentAmount() {
         return new BigDecimal(123);
     }
     public  long getScheduledPaymentConfirmationNumber() {
         return 123L;
     }
}
```

Assertion Error..

```
java.lang.AssertionError: unexpected invocation: paymentProgramScheduledPaymentTypeTestWrapper.getScheduledPaymentAmount()
no expectations specified: did you...
 - forget to start an expectation with a cardinality clause?
 - call a mocked method to specify the parameter of an expectation?
what happened before this: nothing!
    at org.jmock.internal.InvocationDispatcher.dispatch(InvocationDispatcher.java:56)
    at org.jmock.Mockery.dispatch(Mockery.java:218)
    at org.jmock.Mockery.access$000(Mockery.java:43)
    at org.jmock.Mockery$MockObject.invoke(Mockery.java:258)
```

Comment: I believe this is the class of error the message alludes to when it asks "did you" "call a mocked method to specify the parameter of an expectation?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the JMock API incorrectly. It should be

```
public void testFromWebService() {

    mockery.checking(new Expectations() {{

                //debugger throws error on the line below.
                allowing(paymentType).getScheduledPaymentAmount();
                will(returnValue(new BigDecimal(123)));
                allowing(paymentType).getScheduledPaymentConfirmationNumber();
                will(returnValue(121212L));
    }});

}
```

This is saying that when you call the method under test (which you don't seem to be doing in your test) you will expect calls to those methods to return those values. The PaymentType would be a dependency in your class under test which you are mocking.

See [JMock Getting Started](http://www.jmock.org/getting-started.html)

Also, you have a compliation error in the @Before method

Comment: I just dint pay attention to those braces. Thanks for pointing Bedwyr!